# Can I ask a hardware recommendation question, if it is strictly bind to a period of time and problem solved?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are all hardware recommendation-recommendation questions strictly banned here? Or under certain conditions it is allowed to ask such question?

I'd like to ask a question that is strictly bind to a quite specific problem being solved (a phone with a true-glass, non-plastic lens on camera viewport) and to a period of time (end of 2022):

**What would be the best phone (in terms of popularity) to offer a glass-only, non-plastic camera lenses to be purchased by the end of 2022?**

My (maybe false) assumption is that such question has at least certain value through time, because it brings future reader a knowledge of:

1. If glass-only lenses were available for Android-based phones at all?
2. Was there any specific gear of hardware with such lenses by the end of year 2022?
3. If there were more than one such model, which one gained highest popularity and why?

But, I'd like to avoid asking a question that will get nearly immediately closed. Thus asking here first. Thanks.